# Duplicating Objects/Arrays in Java

Tags: java

I have an object with an array as parameter and I'm trying to copy that object in a way I can modify one without modifying the other.
Here's my class:

```
public class Matrix {
 int rows[];

 Matrix() {
    rows = new int[9];
 }

 int[] getRows() {
    return rows;
 }

 void setRow(int x, int y) {
    rows[x] = y;
 }

 int getRow(int x) {
    return rows[x];
 }
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
(Consider Object Matriz x is all filled with values)
Matrix k = new Matrix();
k = x;
(Now I want to modify a specific column without of k without modifying a column of x)
k.setRow(3, 3);
```

But what happens is I get both arrays as same because of the reference when I do k = x;

How can I avoid this and duplicate them instead of creating references? I would like to avoid copying cell by cell to avoid an increase of the run time. (One solution is creating a primitive class Matriz with a sub-class Cell with int values, but besides that?)

Thanks

Comment: You want two independent copies of the data, but you don't want to copy the data? How is that supposed to work? You won't get around implementing some kind of deep-copy for your class.

Comment: I just want to be able to have a matrix, and create another matrix equal to the first, but to be able to modify it without modifying the first one. It's a clone and this is basic stuff that has to be possible..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you call your class `Matrix`, but it's not a matrix. It only has one dimension, so `Vector` would be more accurate.

In order to duplicate your instance, you can use a copy constructor.

```
Matrix(Matrix other) {
    rows = Arrays.copyOf(other.rows, other.rows.length);
}
```

You create a copy of x by :

```
Matrix k = new Matrix(x);
```

Comment: What if I had a multidimensional matrix, let's say a bidimensional. Do I have to use Arrays.copy the number of times as the lines of the matrix?

Comment: @Eran I must be blind or something

Comment: @PedroBarros If your member was a multi-dimentional array, you'll have to create a copy of it by yourself, using a nested for loop. `copyOf` only handles 1D arrays.

Comment: Baaah, I guess I just have to accept it's going to be slow with multidimensional and there's no workaround :p

Answer (score 1):

You could make a second constructer that takes another Matrix as parameter and copys it.

```
public Matrix(Matrix matrix) {
   int[] matrixRows = m.getRows();

   this.rows = new int[matrixRows.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < matrixRows.length; i++) {
       this.rows[i] = matrixRows[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new `Matrix`. 
As `rows` is an array of integer, you can simply use `Arrays.copyOf(rows, rows.length)` to copy it.

There are two common ways:

1/ Create a constructor which take a `Matrix` as input:

```
public Matrix(Matrix matrix){
  this.rows = Arrays.copyOf(matrix.rows, matrix.rows.length);
}
```

then `Matrix k = new Matrix(x);`

2/ implements `Cloneable`:

```
@Override
public Matrix clone() {
  Matrix m = new Matrix();
  m.rows = Arrays.copyOf(this.rows, this.rows.length);
  return m;
}
```

then `Matrix k = x.clone();`

Of course, you can also mix these two approaches :)